# Could not, could not have, was not able to. Which one to use in the question below?

Tags: word-choice

If a situation is happening in the present that did not exist in the past and I want to express that I was unable to foresee what is happening now, which of these sentences should I use?

1. I could not foresee this sad outcome.
2. I could not have foreseen this sad outcome.
3. I was unable to foresee this sad outcome.

Comment: (2) seems the most natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kate  ( Choice #2 is correct ).   Number 3 is also acceptable, but not quite as accurate.

Option 2 is preferable - "Could not have" + verb (forseen) = because it addresses the situation using the conditional tense ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional – RickyBobby yesterday

Option 3 is acceptable because the construction: I was unable to + VERB (present tense) is "softer" than: I could not + VERB (present tense). Option 1 is "so direct" - it would be how I would imagine Commander Data from Star Trek the Next Generation would discuss the situation – RickyBobby yesterday

Comment: Option 2 is preferable - "Could not have" + verb  (forseen) = because it addresses the situation using the conditional tense    https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/

Comment: Option 3 is acceptable because the construction:   I was unable to + VERB (present tense) is "softer" than:  I could not + VERB (present tense).   Option 1 is "so direct" - it would be how I would imagine Commander Data from Star Trek the Next Generation would discuss the situation